# Bind geo load balancing vs Nginx geo load balancing

Tags: nginx, bind

I want to set up the GEO based load balancing server, which solution is better? Bind or Nginx or combining bind and nginx ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, neither are load balancers. You should probably get familiar with both pieces of software first and see which one suits you're needs better. There is no best, only a best fit.